# Is there a way to listen to the last call made on a Nexus?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, voicemail

Is there a way to listen to the last, or one of the last phone calls made on an Android Nexus without the help of an App?

**Situation:** My dead man made his final call to his contact who lived next door, but that guy doesn't remember much of the conversation.

Comment: Calls are not recorded on the phone, and usually also not otherwise (except if one explicitly triggered a recording device/app or the phone is "tapped").

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't as calls aren't recorded by default or even stored temporarily.

Sorry this didn't add any more information than Izzy offered in the comment just thought it should be put as the answer. If you're in a similar situation in the future or need to record a call there are [plenty of apps available](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=call%20recorder) that will let you do that.